# Subtracting from len([list]) python

Tags: python, list, element

I am new in python and wondering for list

```
a= [blabla, lala, haha, test]
```

can i do a subtraction like

```
b= 10- len([a])
```

if not whats the way to do subtract from the number of elements in a list?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: I did and then they said the name in my list is not defined?

Comment: Do you mean "is `b= 10- len([a])` legal code?" Yes it is, but in this case you want `b= 10- len(a)`. `len([a])` means "the length of a list with one element - another list called `a`".

Comment: You should be doing - `len(a)` instead.

Comment: a= [ boar, lala]

b= 3- len(a)

print b

Comment: you need quotes around the elements in a - `"test"` not `test` etc.

Comment: they said boar is undefined?

Comment: try: a=['blabla', 'lala', 'haha', 'test'] and then b= 10- len(a)

Comment: ah i see! i wll try again!

Comment: it works now! with len(a)! thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you mean:

```
a = ['blabla', 'lala', 'haha', 'test']
b = 10 - len(a)

b
=> 6 # 10 - 4 == 6
```

Yes, you can do that :-) . In your code this part won't work as you expect: `len([a])` because that's finding the length of a list with the single element `a`, which also happens to be a list - and it will always evaluate to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

`[a]` is a *new* list containing only `a`, so its length is always `1`, meaning `b` will always be `10 - 1 == 9`.

You likely meant

```
b = 10 - len(a)
```

See [`len()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to shorten the list.  You said you wanted to subtract from the number of elements in the list

```
b = a[:-10]
```

will delete the last 10 elements and store them in `b`, `a` will remain the same

*edit* I might be misunderstanding your english

Also, `10 - len([a])` will always be `9` because `[a]` is a list of size `1` and `10-1=9`, `len(a)` will tell you how long `a` is.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this:

```
b = 10 - len([a])
```

to this:

```
b = 10 - len(a)
```

The issue with `b = 10 - len([a])` is that `[a]` will be a list with a single element, namely the list `a` (which is `['blabla', 'lala', 'haha', 'test']`).

`len(a)` should give you the length of the list `a`.